# Issue with custom gridview Android

Tags: java, android

I have developed an app in which I display data in `Gridview`. All data comes from local storage. I am able to display each data correctly and there are no issues with it. But when I have scroll the `Gridview` and goto the bottom and getback to `Top`,it changes position. And sometimes when I scroll down and getback to Top, a blank screen appears on screen;no data found at all!

So I thought that there is issue with `getView()`. I am unable to figure out the problem

Code of `getView()`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder viewholder;
    // LayoutInflater inflator = activit.getLayoutInflater();
    if(convertView == null) {
        // recycled view is null so create it.
        viewholder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.gridviewrow, null);
        viewholder.imgvGridicon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgvGridicon);
        viewholder.txtGridItemlabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtGridItemlabel);
        convertView.setTag(viewholder); 
    } else {
        viewholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();      
    }  
    if ((lstpinfo.get(position).appname.toString()) != null) {
        viewholder.imgvGridicon.setImageDrawable((lstpinfo.get(position).icon));
        viewholder.txtGridItemlabel.setText(lstpinfo.get(position).appname.toString());
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

**Update:: 
Intitalize of inflater::**

```
private LayoutInflater inflator;

     private ArrayList<PInfo> lstpinfo = new ArrayList<PInfo>();
     public GridViewAdapter(Context cntx, ArrayList<PInfo> lstpinfo) {

            activit = cntx;
            inflator = LayoutInflater.from(cntx);
            this.lstpinfo = lstpinfo;

        }
```

Comment: `lstpinfo` is your local `List` or you are using a static array? I think there should be no problem other the `lstpinfo`

Comment: @user1381267 please see my answer and if you have any issue then tell me.

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem its not problem regarding data .. but its regarding display... so it must be in getview

Comment: where have you initialized inflater??

Comment: OK jut give a try to this use `View rowView = convertView;` and in rest of method use `rowView`. instead of `convertView` and also use `return rowView`.

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem no still not getting effect

Comment: @AkashG i have make update please check it

Comment: initialize it inside getView() as inflator=(LayoutInflater) activit.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Comment: can you mention the logic behind it why i am initialize it in getView?

Comment: @AkashG the situation is now out of control by implement this code..

Comment: you are checking condition if(convertView == null) than only we are inflating layout.so it is good practice of initializing inflater there

Comment: if its not working than initialize inflater in the constructor of adapter,bt same what i commented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set your view height with fixed value. There's a scrolling bug in android gridview with different heights. Please see [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16218) for reference.